# Why can't ngnix or docker see the index.php file?

Tags: php, docker, nginx, drupal

I created my project folder in Ubuntu at: `/home/my_username/Projects/drupal9doc1`
And put in this folder: [Docker-based Drupal stack](https://github.com/wodby/docker4drupal)
Configured the `docker-compose.yml` and `.env` files and then wrote the command in the terminal: `docker-compose up -d`
 running the necessary images for the local rise of the Drupal site.

I created **index.php** files with `phpinfo()` function in my project folder to test how everything works.
I wrote in the url `http://drupal9doc1.localhost:8000`
And **File not found** is displayed on my page  page instead of the php version.

[Part of the code in the **docker-compose.yml** file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzbyZ.png)

[Part of the code in the **.env** file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1HEI.png)

Do you have any suggestions as to why the index.php file for a nginx / docker is not visible? 
If you need more information, write me in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

First, check if the nginx settings match the current project folder: /home/my_username/Projects/drupal9doc1
check the permissions to execute the folder, and check if nginx is really going up, or is having errors.

Comment: Could you tell me how to do it in more detail? Because I'm still a beginner.

Comment: Did you read the docker4drupal docs? https://wodby.com/docs/1.0/stacks/drupal/local/#mount-my-codebase. specifically the part that says "nsure NGINX_SERVER_ROOT (or APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT) is correct, by default set to /var/www/html/web for composer-based projects where Drupal is in web subdirectory"

Comment: @2pha But I don't have composer-based projects! I will download drupal from drupal.org in the archive!
In addition, I have not even reached the stage of downloading / installing Drupal. At the moment I'm just test how work my running images. And I can check it by creating a file index.php which will simply display the PHP version due to the fact that it has a written function phpinfo();

Answer (score 0):

Solution: You need to DELETE the `docker-compose-override.yml` file from project folder and it should work.